# return row only if value not in other row

Tags: sql, ms-access

Have the following subset of tblMember in access 2010:

```
mem_num               product_type           Address    
1                          A                  blah
1                          C                  blah
2                          A                  blah
2                          C                  blah
2                          D                  blah
3                          A                  blah
3                          B                  blah
4                          A                  blah
4                          C                  blah
```

I want to select only rows with product_type 'A', if mem_num does not have product type 'B' in another row or

```
mem_num               product_type          Address
1                          A                  blah
2                          A                  blah
4                          A                  blah
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can Try This query

```
SELECT * FROM tblMember
WHERE product_type = 'A'
      AND mem_num NOT IN (SELECT mem_num FROM 
      tblMember WHERE product_type = 'B' )
```